# Fast multiplication using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I came across a solution for fast multiplication of $2$ numbers. It involves something following:

> Suppose each number has $n = 2m$ digits. Observe that we can split each
> number into two pieces each of $m$ digits, such that the product of the
> full numbers can easily be constructed from the products of the
> pieces, as follows. Let $w = 10^{m+1}$, and represent $A = a_0 + a_1w$ and
> $B = b_0 + b_1w$, where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the pieces of each respective
> number.

I am having hard time wrapping my head around this. How do we express $A$ as $a_0 + a_1w$, and similarly $B$.

An example would really help.

Comment: Let $m = 3$ and $A=123456$, then $A = 456 + 123\times10^3 $

Comment: But then it must be 10 raised to  3+1 as m =3, isn't?

Comment: Probably is an error

Comment: [[1]] Here $ w = 10^{m+1} $ has a typo : It should be $ w = 10^{m} $ [[2]] It will work in Binary too : Eg $ 1101010101 = 10101+11010 \times 2^{5} $ where $ m = 5 $ with $ n = 2m = 2 \times 5 = 10 $